# How to draw nodes with "stubs" in Latex?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to draw this in latex. 
Anyone know how?[image: graph]

Comment: Should be easy if you use tikz - ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using tikz. But I'm new at this and don't know very well the syntax. I know how to draw graph with edges between two nodes, but how can i draw just a "line" from a node?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used tikz, but I think you should just create an empty node, that is without the `draw` option, and connect it to a non-blank node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `calc`-library and do the following:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black, circle, fill=green] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \draw let \p1=(A) in (A) -- (\x1+40,\y1+10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using the `let`-statement it allows you to specify a reference point (or even more) to use it's coordinates for further calculation.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful. Do you know how can I create the "box" with numbers? (as described above in the picture)

Comment: Simply create a node, give it the `draw`-option `rectangle` and type in it's value the numbers.

Comment: I got this error: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/stub' and I am going to i
gnore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` which `tikzlibrary` do I need to add to resove the issue?